# How to make an image with a transparent background in WPF

Tags: wpf, image, transparent

I have a .PNG image displayed in a window. I then want to make the image background the same color as the window. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think there i any way to change the background of a PNG image in WPF. This needs to be done when creating the Image, the area that image doesn't use needs to be made transparent while creating the image.